# Can we fetch public file without asset management method in symfony?

Tags: html, symfony, assets

There are any way to fine public file like image, css and js in symfony without use of assets function!
Because using the assets management they changed the file name after executing the code.

For example at now i am using this function in twig file using the assets management method of symfony.

```
{% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/js/script.js'   %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

This code give me output as below.
HTML view page source view:

```
<script src="/js/87540e8_script_1.js"></script>
```

so you can see here my js file name is script.js and i am getting file name as 87540e8_script_1.js this.

so please inform me about other way to get public file in symfony so i am get real name in html view.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are searching for this: [Web Assets](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/best_practices/web-assets.html)

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```